# Distribution Orders for Users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have orders and users. I distribute evenly for each user's orders.
I need to redistribute when new users are added. And  it is necessary to take into account the difference between the fulfilled and the limit in the algorithm. If users have made a limit on the first distribution, they do not include in the new distribution and expose the column to the limit value from the column made.

```
    declare @orderCount int
    set @orderCount = 50 --Orders for Distribution

    --Result table
    declare @t table (
    users char(3),
    limit int,
    Made int
    )

    --Add users
    insert into @t (users, limit, Made) values
    ('us1',0,0),
    ('us2',0,0),
    ('us3',0,0)


    --Table for the Distribution algorithm
    declare @c table (
        users char(3),
        limit int,
        Made int,
        Cnt int,
        Rn int
    )

    --Count users and row_number 
    insert into @c
        select
            *,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as Cnt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users) as Rn
        from
            @t

    --var for check new distribution>made
    DECLARE @check int = 0

    --Distribution
    update t
    set @check = (@orderCount/Cnt) + CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             limit=
                CASE WHEN
                    (@check >= t.Made)
                THEN
                    @check                  
                ELSE
                    t.Made
                END
            FROM @t t
                INNER JOIN @c cn ON cn.users=t.users  

    --Test data
    UPDATE @t SET Made=12 WHERE users='us1'
    UPDATE @t SET Made=10 WHERE users='us2'
    UPDATE @t SET Made=5 WHERE users='us3'

    --Check result
    SELECT * FROM @t

    --add to distribution new users
    INSERT INTO @t  (users, limit, Made) values ('us4',0,0)
    INSERT INTO @t  (users, limit, Made) values ('us5',0,0)

    --Clear table
    DELETE FROM @c

    --Check new data
    insert into @c
        select
            *,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as Cnt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users) as Rn
        from
            @t

    --Distribution
    update t
    set @check = (@orderCount/Cnt) + CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             limit=
                CASE WHEN
                    (@check >= t.Made)
                THEN
                    @check                  
                ELSE
                    t.Made
                END
            FROM @t t
                INNER JOIN @c cn ON cn.users=t.users            

    --Check result
    SELECT * FROM @t
```

[image]

It divides the number of orders for users. 50/3 ~16 orders for 1 users. If I add 2 new users then 50/5 ~ 10. But 1 users do 12 orders. 12 more new distribution orders (10). then him past into column limit 12. And 50-12=38. Then 38/4 ~ 9 orders the rest uesrs.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Make it easy to help you! Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.)

Comment: I using ms sql server

Comment: @jarlh What don't you understand?

Comment: I'm just too lazy to read all that code...

Comment: I provided the test data. I painted the problem. What else is wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just explain what your algorithym does in words?

Comment: @Pinx0  It divides the number of orders for users. 50/3 ~16 orders for 1 users. If I add 2 new users then 50/5 ~ 10. But 1 users do 12 orders. 12 more new distribution orders (10). then him past into column limit 12. And 50-12=38. Then 38/4 ~ 9 orders the rest uesrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.users, 
        x.work,
        x.Made,
        sum(CASE WHEN Made>NewLimit  THEN  Made ELSE 0 END) OVER() as Dif,
        count(CASE WHEN Made<NewLimit  THEN NewLimit END) OVER() as Cnt,
        CASE WHEN Made>NewLimit THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsUsed,
        (CASE WHEN Made<NewLimit THEN
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.work, (case when Made<NewLimit then 1 else 0 end) ORDER BY work) ELSE 0 END) as Rn
FROM (
SELECT t.users ,(@orderCount/Cnt) + CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as NewLimit,
         t.Made,
         t.work     
    FROM @t t
        INNER JOIN @c cn ON cn.users=t.users
        ) x
```

I consider the amount where the old distribution is more. I'm setting the isUsed flag for the new distribution. I consider the number. I deduct from all orders the amount where the new lehmite is accustomed and divide the amount received for a quantity that is suitable for a new distribution.